# Does nginx-rtmp provide interface to get current live stream info

Tags: nginx

As we know,nginx-rtmp provides stat function, but the result style is  web page. I have several nginx server, I want to collect all the live streams info in these nginx server, and integrate them into my web system.So does nginx provide interface to get these info or is there any other idea to do it?
THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

It also provides a stat.xml based on which the xsl builds the html. You can programatically parse the xml structure and build a list of the currently running streams on your server.